# ExtJS 4.0 : Create Basic Form from existing markup

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I am trying to create a Basic Form from an existing markup. I did that in ExtJS 3.3 easily this way:

```
var formEl = document.createElement('form');

........

var formSubmit = new Ext.form.BasicForm(formEl, {
            method:'POST',
            fileUpload:true
        });
```

It worked as Ext 3.3 Basic Form used to accept form id or element DOM as first param. But in Ext 4.0, there is no such option. I need to submit this Basic Form later.

Can you tell me: is there any other option in ExtJS 4 to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately that cannot work with Ext JS 4.

In Ext 4 forms are not bound to actual HTML form elements. 
Instead on submit temporary form element is generated and submitted to the server.

You should submit your form using JS. Here is an [example](http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml) how to do that.

Comment: Ok, I don't know but might be there is some option to do that. However, I was using that for file upload, now I am using simple IFRAME option for doing that. And just used same Ext.getDom(formEl).submit();